# How to filter 2 huge list with millions of item in it with same id

Tags: java, list, java-stream

Here is my 2 list with more than millions of item. Both has same items with same ID. ID is in String. I need only the item which is not same ID.I did this way. But I am sure there must be a better solution and with high permanence:-

```
    List<Transaction> differentList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Transaction tx : foundTransactions ){
        for(Transaction aTx : ArchivedTransactions) 
        {
            if(!tx.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(aTx.getId()) ){
                differentList .add(tx);
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to use stream but I couldn't do that. I guess with stream API should be better. Please suggest me any improvements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try converting it to a `HashMap` first, something like:

```
Set<String> collect = ArchivedTransactions.stream().map(i -> i.getId().toLowerCase())
                                           .collect(Collectors.toSet());

for(Transaction tx : foundTransactions )
    if(!collect.contains(tx.getId()))
       differentList.add(tx);
```

The `Collectors.toSet()` returns a `HashSet`. You can simplify the code to:

```
Set<String> collect = ArchivedTransactions.stream().map(i -> i.getId().toLowerCase())
                                          .collect(Collectors.toSet());

List<Transaction> differentList = foundTransactions.stream()
                                                   .filter(tx -> !collect.contains(tx.getId()))
                                                   .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Adding the `IDs` first into a `HashSet` as an intermediate step will provide you with a much better overall complexity time since ([source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashset-in-java/)):

> Time Complexity of HashSet Operations: The underlying data structure
> for HashSet is hashtable. So amortize (average or usual case) time
> complexity for **add**, remove and look-up (contains method) operation of
> HashSet takes **O(1)** time.

Consequently, the overall `time complexity` of the *`"HashMap"`* solution will be `O(N + M)`, where  `N` and `M` begin the  number of elements in the lists `ArchivedTransactions` and `foundTransactions`, respectively. Nonetheless, `space-wise` you will pay the price of having that extra structure.

Your solution `space-wise` is better, but with a worst time complexity. If `N = M` the time complexity of your solution is `O(N^2)`, whereas the solution with the `HashSet` would be `O(2N)`, hence `O(N)`. This is a huge difference.

Doing just

```
Set<Transaction> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
result.addAll(foundTransactions);
result.addAll(ArchivedTransactions);
```

*alone* will not work, because you explicitly requested:

```
!tx.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(aTx.getId())
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution that comes to my mind is by using a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) which automatically discards duplicate elements.

```
Set<Transaction> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
result.addAll(foundTransactions);
result.addAll(ArchivedTransactions);

//If you want to get a List<Transaction>
List<Transaction> differentList = new ArrayList<>(result);
```

**Note:** I have used `LinkedHashSet` to preserve the insertion order. If the insertion order doesn't matter for you, you can use `HashSet`.